# Savon array/hash confusion

Tags: ruby, xml, xml-parsing, nokogiri, savon

When Savon parses XML:

```
<MessageList>
  <TradeMessage ID="4850644"/>
  <TradeMessage ID="4850666"/>
  <TradeMessage ID="4850667"/>
  <TradeMessage ID="4850712"/>
</MessageList>
```

It returns a hash

```
{MessageList: TradeMessage: [{@id: '123'},...,{@id: '456'}]}
```

But if the XML is like

```
<MessageList>
  <TradeMessage ID="4850644"/>
</MessageList>
```

it will return

```
{MessageList: TradeMessage: {@id: '123'}}
```

so I can't loop through Message list because it can be a hash or an array.

My code to loop through an array is:

```
t[:message_list][:trade_message].each do |m|
  TradeMessage.create(id: m[:@id])
end
```

What do I do in such a situation? Should I change the XML parser from the default Nokogiri to something else?

I noticed that `Hash.from_xml(string)` returns a hash similar to Savon, an array if several tags, a hash if one tag.

---

I decided to use Nokogiri document to parse Savon's response `response.doc`

Answer (score 1):

If that's Savon's default behaviour, I'd suggest looking at the type of result you get and parsing from there:

```
if t[:message_list][:trade_message].is_a?(Array) # or perhaps `t[:message_list][:trade_message].respond_to?(:each)`
  t[:message_list][:trade_message].each { |m| TradeMessage.create(id: m[:@id]) }
else
  TradeMessage.create(id: t[:message_list][:trade_message][:@id])
end
```

Alternatively, you could wrap the result in an array if it's not already one, and process similarly:

```
t[:message_list][:trade_message].is_a?(Array) ? t[:message_list][:trade_message] : [t[:message_list][:trade_message]]
t[:message_list][:trade_message].each { |m| TradeMessage.create(id: m[:@id]) }
```

That's strange behaviour from the gem though, and it might be worth looking into their docs to see if there's something you can use to alter this behaviour.

Comment: I decided  to parse using nokogiri document
And i've noticed, that `Hash.from_xml(string)` return hash similiar to savon - array if several tags, hash if one tag

Comment: Ah, very odd X-) Did this answer help create the data as desired @nuT707?

Comment: your answer? It's obvious decision, but i need to parse a lot of xml and don't want every time check is it array or  hash. Parsing with nokogiri looks more easy in this case. BUT!) With nokogiri i have some issues too) Look my another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52886666/searching-savon-response-as-nokogiri-document-returns-an-empty-array)

Answer (score 1):

You could use Ruby's splat operator. It will always return an array. Please see below for a extremely simple example:

```
require 'awesome_print'

def return_array(elements)
  return *elements
end

ap return_array([:a, :b, :c])
ap return_array(:d)
```