# Searching savon response as nokogiri document returns an empty array

Tags: ruby, xml, xml-parsing, nokogiri, savon

I try to parse savon's response as nokokiri document

```
c = Savon.client(wsdl: 'http://test.fedresurs.ru/MessageService/WebService.svc?wsdl', digest_auth: ['demowebuser', 'Ax!761BN'], namespace: "http://tempuri.org/", namespace_identifier: :tem, log: true)
r = c.call(:get_trade_messages, message: {'tem:startFrom' => DateTime.now-1})
r.doc.search("TradePlace")
```

and it returns an empty array.

What I'm doing wrong? May be I should deal somehow with namespaces? But, how?. Examples, that I found in nokogiri documentation use Xpath, not search. And even with Xpath it returns an empty array.

XML-response:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
      <GetTradeMessagesResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
         <GetTradeMessagesResult>
            <TradePlace INN="7606055642" Name="Первая электронная площадка " Site="1torgi.ru " OwnerName="ООО &quot;Промтех&quot;">
               <TradeList>
                  <Trade ID_External="ЗКОФЦП-17136" ID_EFRSB="653476">
                     <MessageList>
                        <TradeMessage ID="4851134"/>
                        <TradeMessage ID="4851135"/>
                     </MessageList>
                  </Trade>
               </TradeList>
            </TradePlace>
         </GetTradeMessagesResult>
      </GetTradeMessagesResponse>
   </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Comment: Have you tried to execute the SOAP request using SoapUI? That should *always* be your first test. Does SoapUI return the expected result?

Comment: @SteffenRoller of course, it's all ok with response result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I expected the answer was in namespace, code below works fine:

```
r.doc.search("a|TradePlace", {"a" => "http://tempuri.org/"})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Nokogiri` to break apart the XML response.
A (now nofunctional) example is this:

```
doc = Nokogiri::XML(response.to_hash[:get_quote_response][:get_quote_result])
print doc.to_xml(indent: 2)

print "Date      : ", doc.at_css("Date").text, "\n"
print "Last price: ", doc.at_css("Last").text
```

are more complete example in my pastebin https://pastebin.com/W0RUuaHU. The WebserviceX was unfortunately discontinued.

Comment: good idea, but not working and have no idea how to parse hash with nokogiri. May be you know?

Comment: you were talking about XML destructering, that's why I brought up Nokogiri. I assume you have turned your results into a hash with `.to_hash` and have printed with `awesome_print`? That's how I made my way through unknown data structures.

Comment: As you can see from my response, I first create the XML structure from the hash and _then_ use Nokogiri to find the elements using CSS syntax.